# Composing decorator with parameters in python

Tags: python, flask, parameter-passing, python-decorators

I want to use a decorator (**composer**) that recevices as parameter *n* number of decorators, this decorators will be used to decorate a function. Also I want to pass some parameters from two origins, a parameter named "SKIP" in the **composer** and another parameter named "parameter" sent by the **parameter_sender** decorator. Here's what I tried:

```
def compose(*decorators, SKIP=None):
def something(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrap(parameter = None, **kwargs):
        try:
            if SKIP:
                print("I'm here")
                return func(parameter = parameter,**kwargs) 
            else:
                for decorator in reversed(decorators):
                    func = decorator(func, parameter = parameter,**kwargs) # --------- This line is providing the error ------------------
                return func
            raise exception
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise exception
    return func_wrap
return something
```

And here is an example of where do I want to use it. In this example I want to SKIP the composing of all the decorators if the variable SKIP is true.

```
@application.route("/function/<id_something>", methods=['GET'])
@parameter_sender
@compose(decorator_1,decorator_2, SKIP=True)
def function (id_something, **kwargs):
    try:
        #TODO:
        return jsonify("ok")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But i've got an error that says this:

```
>>I'm here
>>local variable 'func' referenced before assignment
```

Even when the if statement is working. PD: It works without the line indicated in the **composer**.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with those decorators ? If you want composition a simpler way could be to use class based views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the thing.
You were trying to set a value for a variable from outer scope. In my example I used separate temp variable composition.

```py
def compose(*decorators, SKIP=None):
    def something(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                if SKIP:
                    print("I'm here")
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    composition = func
                    for decorator in reversed(decorators):
                        composition = decorator(composition)
                    return composition(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                raise
        return func_wrap
    return something
```